# Find SQL element that matches properties stored in a dictionary of a target using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using `.Net 6` and `EF Core 7`,

I have a DbSet of `Candidates`. Each candidate has an `Id` and a list of `Language` objects that stores the `LanguageId` and the `LanguageLevel`.
To search for a `Candidate`, I got a `TargetProfile` with a dictionary, storing `LanguageIds` as key and `LanguageLevels` as values.

```cs
public class CandidateEntity {
   public List<LanguageEntity> Languages;
}

public class LanguageEntity {
  public int LanguageId;
  public int LanguageLevel;
}

public class TargetProfileDto {
  public Dictionary<int,int> Languages;
}
```

The candidates need to match both the language and level requirements.

I tried something like this where I checked, if any required language would remain after I remove all that match

```cs
var matches = from candidate in DbContext.Candidates
where
!targetProfile.Languages.Keys.Except(candidate.Languages
   .Where(l => targetProfile.Languages.Keys.Contains(l.LanguageId) &&
    targetProfile.Languages[l.LanguageId] <= l.Level).Select(l => l.LanguageId))
   .Any()
select candidate;
```

but when I try to execute via ToList(), I get an entity framework error, that my query is too complex.

> 'The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

I then tried using `LINQ`, but I have not found a way to access the dictionary dynamically.

Is there a good way to have something like this?

```cs
var result = DbContext.candidates.Where(
   candidate => {
   foreach(language in candidate.Language) => {
   targetProfile[language.LanguageId) == language.LanguageLevel;
   }}).ToList();
```

I know how to do this in plain C#, but not as a EF Core query.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your logic.
Normally I would expect: candidate.Language.LanguageId to refer to a language row, where the Id = the value in this column, but you compare it to a language level?

Provided you have set up PK/FK relationships : 

DbContext.candidates.Where(
   candidate => candidate.Language.LanguageId == candidate.Language.LanguageLevel
   ).ToList();

Would be valid syntax, I am just pretty sure, it would not return what you want :D

Comment: I corrected my candidate class :D I have a List of languages, and I just want to get only candidates with the languages and levels stored in the profile

Comment: Probably best to just use a Table Valued Parameter and a custom SQL Procedure

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. The code is definitely wrong and can never work. LINQ isn't an alternative to SQL, it gets translated to SQL. You can't specify something that can't be translated to SQL. Local function calls can't be translated. You certainly can't translate loops - that's simply not a concept in SELECT queries

Comment: In SQL, if you wanted to filter by a list of values you'd use `IN (value1, value2,...)`. To do the same in LINQ you'd have to write `where listOfValues.Contains(myObject.Field)`

Comment: As for using `Dictionary<int,int>`, what would this map to? If anything, that should be a table in itself. If you have a table with `ProfileId, FromLanguageId,ToLanguageID` you can write queries based on those fields

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the dictionary is not from the data base. Only the candidate is.
I have a target in my business logic and it is used to search for candidates from the data base

Comment: How do you expect this to get translated to SQL then? EF Core is an ORM - it Maps Objects to Relational structures. The name matters because it says an ORM has a very limited scope - Mapping rows to Objects. ORMs can retrieve rows by their PKs and map them to objects, or execute SQL queries and map the results. More advanced ORMs have query languages like Hibernate's HQL or EF Core's LINQ but these are still converted to SQL.

Comment: EF is able to search inside the data base for properties of its entities and return the right one. I could also store the target inside the data base. The only problem I have is, that I dont know how to search for multiple matches. The candidate is inside the database and the target is basically also a candidate. So it should be possible to find a candidate that matches another candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such query needs dynamic expression building. Idea is to build expression like this:

```cs
var query = DbContext.Candidates
    .Where(c => c.Languages.Count(l => l.LanguageId == 1 && l.LanguageLevel == 2 || l.LanguageId == 2 && l.LanguageLevel == 3 || ...) 
       == targetProfile.Languages.Count);
```

One requirement for such approcach: match items should be list of unique items, which is guaranteed by `Dictionary` container.

Usage is simple:

```cs
var query = DbContext.Candidates
    .MatchByCriteria(targetProfile.Languages, c => c.Languages, (l, t) => l.LanguageId == t.LanguageId && l.LanguageLevel == t.LanguageLevel)
```

And realuisation:

```cs
public static class MatchExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> MatchByCriteria<TEntity, TProp, TItem>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query, 
        IEnumerable<TItem> items, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProp>>> prop, 
        Expression<Func<TProp, TItem, bool>> filterPattern)
    {
        var itemsList = items.ToList();
        var matchPredicate = GetItemsPredicate(itemsList, filterPattern);

        var propBody = prop.Body;

        // e.SomeCollection.Count(matchPredicate)
        var countExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Count), new[] { typeof(TProp) },
            propBody, matchPredicate);

        // e.SomeCollection.Count(matchPredicate) == items.Count
        var equalsExpr = Expression.Equal(countExpr, Expression.Constant(itemsList.Count));

        // e => e.SomeCollection.Count(matchPredicate) == items.Count
        var matchLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equalsExpr, prop.Parameters[0]);

        // query.Where(e => e.SomeCollection.Count(matchPredicate) == items.Count)
        return query.Where(matchLambda);
    }


    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetItemsPredicate<TEntity, TItem>(
        IEnumerable<TItem> items, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TItem, bool>> filterPattern, bool isOr = true, bool emptyValue = false)
    {
        Expression? predicate = null;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemExpr = Expression.Constant(item);
            var itemCondition = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterPattern.Parameters[1], itemExpr, filterPattern.Body);
            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = itemCondition;
            else
            {
                predicate = Expression.MakeBinary(isOr ? ExpressionType.OrElse : ExpressionType.AndAlso, predicate,
                    itemCondition);
            }
        }

        predicate ??= Expression.Constant(emptyValue);
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, filterPattern.Parameters[0]);
        return filterLambda;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I can currently not include additional packages to my project and thus would like to have an answer that works with the standard LINQ Syntax

Comment: Added another approach. I do not understand your question about list of languages.

Comment: if the candidate would have only one language to check, I would know a solution. My problem here is, that I need to check basically two lists, one of the candidate and one of the target. So only one foreach is not enough I think

Comment: I see only one list in question `TargetProfile.Languages` - enumeration of KeyValuePair. If you have something to explain - add to the question.

Comment: There are two, `TargetProfile.Languages` and `Candidate.Languages`

Comment: I see. Do you have Profiles Table or Languages table? Show their classes. It is needed to generate correct LINQ query.

Comment: The profile is just a DTO, so it has no table.

Comment: Added realization of such algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to work out of the box. I just dont fully understand your extension yet :D.